# Proving $\frac{a}{a^2+2b^2}+\frac{b}{b^2+2c^2}+\frac{c}{c^2+2a^2}\geq 1$ when $a^2+b^2+c^2=a^3+b^3+c^3$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, muirhead-inequality

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3475203/631742), @MichaelRozenberg stated the following inequality:

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers such that $a^3+b^3+c^3=a^2+b^2+c^2.$ Then
>   $$\frac{a}{a^2+2b^2}+\frac{b}{b^2+2c^2}+\frac{c}{c^2+2a^2}\geq 1.$$

---

Edit: Here is a brute force way:

For $a,b,c>0$ we can prove $$\frac{a}{a^2+2b^2}+\frac{b}{b^2+2c^2}+\frac{c}{c^2+2a^2}\geq\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a^3+b^3+c^3}.$$

Assume WLOG that $a\le b$ and $a\le c$. So $b=a+x$ and $c=a+y$ for some $x,y>0$. Then the above inequality is equivalent to $$42 a^6 \left(x^2-x y+y^2\right)+6 a^5 \left(15 x^3+4 x^2 y-7 x y^2+15 y^3\right)+10    a^4 \left(9 x^4+10 x^3 y-x y^3+9 y^4\right)+a^3 \left(50 x^5+103 x^4 y+34 x^3    y^2+6 x^2 y^3+7 x y^4+50 y^5\right)+a^2 \left(14 x^6+57 x^5 y+27 x^4 y^2+10 x^3    y^3+3 x^2 y^4+9 x y^5+14 y^6\right)+a \left(2 x^7+14 x^6 y+13 x^5 y^2+4 x^4 y^3-4    x^3 y^4+7 x^2 y^5+2 y^7\right)+2 x^3 y \left(x^4+2 x^2 y^2-2 x y^3+y^4\right)\geq0$$ which is true because

- $x^2-xy+y^2=xy+(x-y)^2\geq 0$,
- $15 x^3+4x^2y-7xy^2+15y^3=8(x^3+y^3)+11x^2y+7(x-y)^2(x+y)\geq0$,
- $9 x^4+10 x^3 y - x y^3 +9y^4=8(x^4+y^4) + 11 x^3 y+(x-y)^2(x^2+xy+y^2)$,
- $x^4+2x^2y^2-2xy^3+y^4=x^4+x^2y^2+y^2(x-y)^2\geq0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant the following solution.

By C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+2b^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2(a+2c)^2}{a(a+2c)^2(a^2+2b^2)}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}a(a+2c)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}a(a+2c)^2(a^2+2b^2)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$(a+b+c)^4(a^3+b^3+c^3)\geq(a^2+b^2+c^2)\sum\limits_{cyc}a(a+2c)^2(a^2+2b^2)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^6b+3a^5b^2+a^5c^2+a^4b^3-a^4c^3+12a^5bc-8a^4b^2c-4a^4c^2b+8a^3b^3c-16a^3b^2c^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(4a^6b+2a^5b^2+2a^4b^3-4a^4b^2c-4a^3b^2c^2)+$$
$$+\sum_{cyc}(a^5b^2+a^5c^2-a^4b^3-a^4c^3+12a^5bc-4a^4b^2c-4a^4c^2b+8a^3b^3c-12a^3b^2c^2)\geq0,$$
which is true by AM-GM and Muirhead.

Comment: Nice. Oftentimes I see that you first expand fractions before using Cauchy-Schwarz. For example, here you expand: $$\frac{a}{a^2+2b^2}=\frac{a^2 (a+2c)^2}{a(a+2c)^2(a^2+2b^2)}$$ Is there some systematic reasoning behind choosing how to rewrite the fractions or is it just "by intuition" ?

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch It's more intuition than something systematic. By the way,  we can try to reduce an influence of $2b^2,$ for which we took $a(a+2c)^2.$ I tried also $a(a+c)^2$. It also gives a proof, but with greater work.

Answer (score 0):

I would write $$\frac{a}{a^2+2b^2}+\frac{b}{b^2+2c^2}+\frac{c}{c^2+2a^2}\geq \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a^3+b^3+c^3}$$

Comment: Your inequality always holds and is, by Buffalo ($b=a+x$, $c=a+y$) , equivalent to $$42 a^6 \left(x^2-x y+y^2\right)+6 a^5 \left(15 x^3+4 x^2 y-7 x y^2+15 y^3\right)+10
   a^4 \left(9 x^4+10 x^3 y-x y^3+9 y^4\right)+a^3 \left(50 x^5+103 x^4 y+34 x^3
   y^2+6 x^2 y^3+7 x y^4+50 y^5\right)+a^2 \left(14 x^6+57 x^5 y+27 x^4 y^2+10 x^3
   y^3+3 x^2 y^4+9 x y^5+14 y^6\right)+a \left(2 x^7+14 x^6 y+13 x^5 y^2+4 x^4 y^3-4
   x^3 y^4+7 x^2 y^5+2 y^7\right)+2 x^3 y \left(x^4+2 x^2 y^2-2 x y^3+y^4\right)\geq0$$ which is true. Do you think that there is an easier way?